# Binder from Android to chroot linux

Tags: applications, root-access

Situation:
Android OS that runs chroot'ed Ubuntu.
As i understand Ubuntu does work on top of android linux kernel,
which have integrated Binder interface, i checked [few examples here](https://ebixio.com/blog/2012/07/07/using-android-ipc-binders-from-native-code/).

Does it mean that i can compile this 'client' library for ubuntu that will use binder /dev/binder?
And at same time have an android application that will act as 'server'?
The idea is to get IPC working between these two systems.

Comment: Yes it will work. But the native binder library isn't available in Ubuntu chroot. You'll have build the library / binary with Android NDK (not with GCC) and copy the shared libraries from `/system/lib[64]/` to Ubuntu's `/lib/`.

Comment: thats not gonna work then because i cant use android Bionic from ubuntu

Comment: Linking to Android libraries with Ubuntu's GCC or building statically linked libraries is a big challenge. So better go for some other option. Why not simply use socket? If you own the app.